# Choose another TextInputLayout style

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to make a TextInputLayout that, when clicked, doesn't show a smaller hint on the top left corner and doesn't have a giant underline so the default TextInputLayout style when the Layout is clicked isn't good for my app.

Where can I find a list of all possible style or how can I change that manually?

Comment: Can you show required UI?

Comment: you can also use EditText as stand-alone it will not show title after you enter text.

Comment: @Khemraj A simple TextInputLayout when hint disappear and user can write (e.g. Twitter Search)

Comment: You can use EditText instead. TextInputLayout is used for floating hint.

Comment: Yes with EditText works perfectly. Thanks a lot!